# How to find the latest survey an employee attended?

Tags: mysql

My table structure is as follows:

```
employee_survey_id employee_id took_survey_date visual_percent
                27          10 2014-08-03                   37
                29          10 2012-09-11                   33
                30           4 2014-11-03                   30
                31           6 2015-03-02                   37
                32          10 2015-03-04                   32
                33           4 2015-03-04                   33
                34           7 2015-03-05                    0
```

I want the list of latest survey information for each employee.

Example:

```
 employee_survey_id     Employee_id  took_survey_date  visual_percent
     32                    10         2015-03-04            32
     33                     4         2015-03-04            33
     31                     6         2015-03-02            37
     34                     7         2015-03-05            0
```

I am using mysql. Hope I have explained my question clearly.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is the query?

Comment: I am a PHP guy. I don't have much idea on sql. I know basic queries. Here I got confused.

Comment: So far I found it for 1 employee : SELECT * FROM `survey` WHERE employee_id = 10 ORDER BY employee_survey_id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Can an employee take two surveys in one day?

Comment: No. But can take survey after certain period.

Comment: This question is asked quite often.

Comment: could you please share the reference link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [group-wise minimum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be found by first grouping the table and then joining the results back:

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT   employee_id, MAX(took_survey_date) took_survey_date
         FROM     myTable
         GROUP BY employee_id
       ) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ab2b/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM employees GROUP BY Employee_id ORDER BY took_survey_date DESC
```

Comment: it doesn't return the desired result. I returns 
`survey_id   employee_id   took_survey_date  Percentage
          27           10                   2014-08-03     37  `

Comment: That's incredible. Returns only one row?

Comment: No. It returns all rows but I pointed out one wrong row for better understanding.